# ImageMagick batch montage all images in subfolders

Tags: image, batch-file, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a folder containing 4 sub-folders, and each sub-folder contains 4 images (for a total of 16 images). I want to combine these 16 images into 1 image.

Example of structure:

```
0/0.png
0/1.png
...
1/0.png
1/1.png
...
3/3.png
```

This is how the images are combined into one image:

[image]

Each column represents a sub-folder.

I have +30 of these folders, and that's why I want to create a script instead of doing it manually in Photoshop.

I downloaded ImageMagick for Windows and tried to create a batch script that I could run.

I tried this:

```
cd %cd%
for /r /d %%a in (*.png) do montage -tile 5x4 "result.png"
```

This doesn't work (no image, nor error in CMD). Please note that I am completely new to both ImageMagick and creating .bat files in Windows.

So, how can modify my script so it goes through all the sub-folders and creates/convert a single montage/tile from all the images in the sub-folders?

Comment: ImageMagick montage does not traverse subdirectories. You will have use access all images in each subdirectory and feed that to montage. Sorry, I do not code in Windows. If image 1-4 is in the same subdirectory, you will need to rearrange images before feeding to montage or transpose the image after montage. In what way does it not work?

Comment: You also need to specify if there is any preference as to the order of those images with respect to the final montage, i.e. which one goes where?

Comment: @fmw42 It does not produce an image at all, but I don't get an error either

Comment: @Compo Please see my updated question, maybe the image will help in understanding the order

Comment: No it doesn't, which file and from which directory is each of those numbers representing? and BTW, I've reduced the image still further.

Comment: @Compo I've updated the question again with the folder structure and filenames

Comment: Montage will not work in vertical stacked order. So you will have to transpose the resulting montage to get that order. You need to collect all the images from each subdirectory in a list and feed the list to montage and then transpose the image. Alternately, perhaps you can put dir1\*.png dir2\*.png .. dir4\*.png as input. Note you are using unix /s when you need windows \s. You should look up more about bat scripting on windows

Comment: `magick 0/*.png -append ( 1/*.png -append ) ( 2/*.png -append ) ( 3/*.png -append ) +append result.png`

Comment: `@Marck Setchell`. Your code is Unix not Windows. Change your slashes and use magick.exe. Good idea to just use append. `magick.exe ( 0\*.png -append ) ( 1\*.png -append ) ( 2\*.png -append ) ( 3\*.png -append ) +append result.png`

Comment: CONTINUED: Loop over each of your 30 directories and use the append command above.

Comment: @fmw42 Works perfect, thank you! If you can make it to an answer, I can accept it

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you, with fmw42 conversion to Windows it works perfectly

Comment: Maybe you could write it up Fred @fmw42 as I am up a glacier in Iceland with flaky Internet and no means to test! Thank you.

Comment: ok, I suggest you remove the `batch-file` tag as it seemed you wanted to automate this, so seems you just wanted the correct command to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know Windows scripting syntax. But if you loop over each directory of your 30 directories and run the following ImageMagick command from Mark Setchell converted to Windows slashes, that should work.

```
magick.exe ( 0\*.png -append ) ( 1\*.png -append ) ( 2\*.png -append ) ( 3\*.png -append ) +append result.png
```

Since I do not know Windows .bat scripting, it is possible that the answer from Gerhard Barnard may do just that.

Answer (score 0):

Your example loops through all images, but you are doing it in the current `dir` only, not sub directories. The command also does not even use the metavariable `%%a` anywhere and if it did, it performs the `do` function to each file seperately.

You could just loop through the images using `dir`, get each and append them using `set /p` in batch. so no matter how many images you have, it should loop through them.. Here I just store the result in a tmp file to use it in another loop, but there are many ways.

```
@echo off
set "myt=%temp%out.tmp"
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /S *.png') do echo| set /p = ("%%~fi" -append)>>"%myt%"
for /f "delims=" %%b in (%myt%) do magick.exe %%b +append result.png
del /Q "%myt%">nul
```

*NOTE* I am not too farmiliar with `magick` so not sure if the double quotes will cause issues, however I doubt it as paths with spaces would should cause issues.